# Compiling Metal shaders from source on iOS 13 Simulator gives PCH error

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, shader, metal

I am working on the [Cocos2d-x v4 branch](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/20040) which introduces Metal backend support and uses [glsl-optimizer](https://github.com/cocos2d/glsl-optimizer) to convert GLSL to MSL for compilation at runtime using [`newLibraryWithSource:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433431-newlibrarywithsource?language=objc).

This works fine compiling using Xcode 11 beta for an iOS 13 device, however when compiling for iOS 13 Simulator the shader fails to compile with the following error:

```
Error: PCH file built from a different branch ((metalfe-902.9.49)) than the compiler ((metalfe-902.9.52))
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

**More details**:  At the time of asking this question I was using Xcode 11 beta 5 on macOS 10.15 beta 5.  I have now updated to macOS 10.15 beta 6 and there is no change.  I suspect this might be solved by an update to Xcode 11 beta.

Comment: Have you tried Xcode 11 beta 6 yet?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Unpacking it now...

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Yes that has solved it.  I now have an issue with an invalid pixel format for the texture, but that's a different story.

Comment: I had something similar. I had to remove the empty `kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey` option when creating textures on the Simulator.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Thank you I will look into that when I get back from my Holiday.  I think there will need to be a fair amount of macOS/Simulator vs iOS conditional code anyway, however this pixel format issue feels like another bug doesn't it.

Comment: Might be. The error messages caused by the empty IOSurface properties were also pretty esoteric, though. Maybe you can post a new question for your problem when you're back. Enjoy your Holiday!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was solved by using Xcode 11 beta 6.